# How to restore a backed-up profile on a new installation?

Tags: windows-10, firefox, migration, firefox-profile

My company made us all downgrade our laptops from Windows 7 to Windows 10. On my computer, I had to go through a full, clean installation, so I lost all my saved data (whatever was not copied to the "cloud").

As a part of the process, I had to reinstall Firefox afresh. Before the re-imaging, I backed up the Firefox profile on my older system, i.e., copied this folder to the backup:

`C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\xyzsusl1.default`

Now, I am trying to restore my profile on the new installation. Following the [instructions in the Mozilla support page](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/back-and-restore-information-firefox-profiles), I renamed the newly created profile to a temp name, then renamed the backed-up profile to the name of the newly created profile.

This method did not work. Next, I restored the newly created profile folder and this time copied the content of the old profile onto the new profile. This did not work either. So last thing, I removed FF (x64) and reinstalled FF (x86), thinking maybe the profiles are not compatible between 32- and 64-bit versions. But this did not work either.

How can I restore my Firefox profile from the backup?

Comment: @Ramhound - I noticed that there is a profile with the same name under the `Roaming` folder. But at the time, I did not back that up. When I remove the *new* profile from `Roaming`, FF won't even start. If I just remove the new profile from `Local` and paste the old one (using the old name) then it won't start. Only when I rename the old to the new name, then FF starts, but I don't get the old settings restored.

Comment: `Cache\ `, `cache2\ `, `jumpListCache\ `, `OfflineCache\ `, `safebrowsing\ `, `startupCache\ `, `thumbnails\ `, `_CACHE_CLEAN_`, `directoryLinks.json`, `frequencyCap.json`.

Comment: That's weird. The new profile that was created with the installation at the location I wrote in the question has exactly the same folder and file structure... Is the profile under `Roaming` the one that should have been backed up?

Comment: Crap. Looks like `%APPDATA%` points to the `Roaming` folder and not the `Local` folder. Luckily, the system downgrade was made on a new, larger SSD, and I got the IT guy to save my old SSD for a couple of days. I will try reinstalling the old drive and backing up the other profile directory.

Comment: How is the transition from Windows 7 to Windows 10 labeled a "downgrade?"

Comment: @Run5k - that's sarcasm.... I find Win 7 user experience to be much better than Win 10's.

Comment: @Ramhound - for starters, the Start menu is horrid, no-edge windows makes it hard to resize and Settings (aka Control Panel) applets are dumbed-down or confusing. I (and everybody else I know) prefers the Win 7 GUI style over the one-size-fits-all-devices style of Win 10.

Comment: In contrast, the very best Windows experts on my team at work all prefer Windows 10, so it's safe so say that they would label it an upgrade. Needless to say it is your question, but you might find that people are a bit more motivated to help you without the unnecessary sarcasm and/or Microsoft bashing,

Comment: Not bashing MS at all. Just the Win 10 experience. Even though, I still choose Windows over Linux when I have the choice, and certainly over OS-X any day! Likewise for Office, VS (although Eclipse is a tough competitor) etc.

Comment: Understood.  However, while we are always glad to help, the unnecessary sarcasm can potentially cause some of us to dismiss your query.  When I see someone intentionally phrase their question with cynical bashing related to something that my entire team of technical experts at work thoroughly enjoys, I tend to assume (fair or not) that they don't fully understand it.

Comment: @Run5k - Appreciate your input. Yet, for me, this move is a downgrade, as it makes my workday harder and less enjoyable. If the person asking "does not fully understand it", then that's a good reason to step in and help, isn't it?? Anyway, let's just keep it the way it is. A little sarcasm or humor (even black humor) did not kill anyone yet. Don't be personally offended, especially over things that are subjective experiences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

+1 for calling Windows 10 a 'downgrade'.

As you mentioned in the comments, the Firefox profile itself is stored under `AppData\Roaming`. Stuff in `AppData\Local` and `AppData\LocalLow` only contain the cache.

You can also do more low-level profile management by running `firefox -profilemanager` or editing the contents of `AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\profiles.ini` (when Firefox isn't running).